# homeomorphism between zero-dimensional Hausdorff and two-point space

Tags: general-topology

Given $\left\{g_{\alpha}: \alpha\in T\right\}$ consists of all continuous functions from $A$ to $\{0,1\}$ ($A$ is a zero-dimensional Hausdorff space). Let $G =\prod_{\alpha\in T} g_{\alpha}: A\rightarrow \left\{0,1\right\}^{T}$, so $G(x) = (g_{\alpha} (x))_{\alpha\in T}$.

Show that $G$ gives a homeomorphism between $A$ and $\{0,1\}^{T}$.

**My progress.** By the definition of $G$, it's easy to see that $G$ is $1$-$1$ and onto as well, so $G$ is a bijection. In addition, since all the components of $G$ are continuous functions, by the universal mapping property, $G$ is also continuous. It remains to show that $G^{-1}$ is continuous as well. Consider the neighborhood $(a,b)$ around the point $0$ (similar for $1$). Now, it's clear that $(G^{-1})^{-1}(a,b)$ is continuous, so can we imply that $G^{-1}$ is continuous because of zero-dimensional Hausdorff space (I can't see how to use this fact anywhere else:P)

Comment: What is $A$? A typo for $X$? What is $F$? A typo for $G$? I suspect that you’ve omitted a hypothesis and misstated the conclusion. Specifically, I suspect that there should be a hypothesis that for each $x,y\in X$ with $x\ne y$ there is an $\alpha\in T$ such that $g_\alpha(x)\ne g_\alpha(y)$ (or something equivalent to this), and that the conclusion should be that $G$ is a homeomorphism between $X$ and $\{0,1\}^T$. (Note: to get $\{$ and $\}$, use `\{` and `\}`.)

Comment: Dear Prof. Scott, you're very correct. My sincere apology. I fixed all the typos now , but there is no assumption about $x\neq y$ as you stated. Can you please try working out this problem?

Comment: note that a hausdorff zero dimensional space is fully disconnected and therefore any function that is 1-1 and onto is a homeomorphism... with that said $F$ and $X$ appear exactly once each in the whole question, and i suspect that $T$ is the cardinal of the set of continuous functions between $A$ and $\{0,1\}$ but the phrasing of the question seems to be a bit misleading in that regard.

Comment: @JohnC: can you please show me the detailed proof for the part that inverse $G^{-1}$ is continuous? Was my proof in the "My progress"for $G$ is $1-1$, onto and continuous correct? I reviewed the question, and the $T$ is exactly what you interpreted. Other than that, I think it's correctly stated now

Comment: So here's my attempt to show that $G$ is a homeomorphism: first, I think we have to assume that $g_{\alpha}$ is $1-1$ and onto, because only in that case, $G(x)$ is $1-1$ and onto (or is it because continuous function between two Hausdorff spaces is $1-1$ and onto?) Now, to show that $F$ is continuous, we first note that since $A$ is zero-dimensional space, it has a basis of sets that are both closed and open. Since $g_{\alpha}$ is continuous, all the components of $G(x)$ is continuous at any point $x$. By the universal mapping property, $G(x)$ must be continuous.

Comment: To show $G^{-1}$ is continuous, since we assume $g_{\alpha}$ is onto, exists basis open sets$x_i$ in X such that $g_{\alpha} (x_i)=1$ for some $\alpha$ and $i$. Thus, $G^{-1}(0)$ = union of $(g_{\alpha})^{-1}(0)$ for some $\alpha$ = union of  all basis open sets, which is also a basis open set. Similar for $G^{-1}(1)$. Thus $G^{-1}$ maps basis element to basis element, so it's continuous. Note that without the assumption $g_{\alpha}$ is $1-1$ and onto, my proof doesn't work. I really don't think we can get this property based on the fact that X is zero-dimensional?

Comment: @JohnC: can you please help review my proof in the 2 posts right above to see if it's correct? thanks very much.

Comment: the biggest probem is that I have no Idea what $F$ and $X$ are since they are not defined, it looks like you might mean $G$ when you say $F$ and $A$ when you say $X$ but that wouldn't really make much sense. Because then the function $G$ would not be onto

Comment: @JohnC: my bad:( I indeed meant to say $G$ when I said $F$ and $A$ when I said $X$. As I said above, what I'm concerning is whether my proof above is correct IF we assume $g_{\alpha}$ is $1-1$ and onto? Can you please help with the proof for the theorem you stated: "any function that is 1-1 and onto from a zero dimensional space to any space (in this case, a discrete space) is a homeomorphism"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $A$ is a zero dimensional Hausdorff space (I assume you mean a zero dimensional manifold, which means that each point has an open neighborhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{0}$, i.e. the one point set) it is comprised entirely of isolated points. So, given any function $f:A\to X$ and any open set $U\subseteq X$, we have $f^{-1}(U) = \bigcup_{a\in f^{-1}(U)}\{a\}$ which is open, i.e. any function from $A$ is continuous.

Much like $A$, if $T$ is finite (i.e. if $A$ is finite) $\{0,1\}^T$ also has  the discrete topology, and therefore any function from $\{0,1\}^T$ is also continuous. If, however $T$ is infinite, then the topology on $\{0,1\}^T$ is gonna depend on which topology you choose (and generally, the canonical topology is such that the basic open sets will be of the form $\prod_{\alpha} U_\alpha$, where $U_\alpha$ differs from $\{0,1\}$ only from finitely many indices, note that in this case $\{0,1\}$ is Hausdorff, and it is not zero-dimensional, since there is no open set comprising a single point).

From the two paragraphs above, we may have that $G$ is a homeomorphism only if $A$ is finite (because otherwise the $G(a) = (G^{-1})^{-1}(\{a\})$ has to have more than one point, since $\{a\}$ is open and we are assuming $G^{-1}$ is continuous).

However, note that $T$ is, the number of funcions $g_\alpha:A\to\{0,1\}$ is equal to $|\mathcal{P}(A)|$, i.e. the number of subsets of $A$, so $\{0,1\}^T$ has $2^{|\mathcal P(A)|} = 2^{2^{|A|}}$ elements, therefore, there can be no bijection between $A$ and $\{0,1\}^T$.

Comment: Many thanks for your elaborated explanation John:) However, I can't see how you got: "if T is finite (i.e. if A is finite) $\{0,1\}^T$ also has the discrete topology, and therefore any function from $\{0,1\}^T$ is also continuous." In addition, what if $g_{\alpha}$ is not $1-1$ for every $\alpha\in T$? Shouldn't $G$ not be $1-1$ in that case as well, so it can't be homeomorphism? Finally, what will occur when $T$ is infinite, $\{0,1\}^T$ still has discrete topology?

Comment: So that's a three part quedtion I will answer accordingly. 1) the two-point set $\{0,1\}$ only has two possible topologies, the discrete topology and the trivial topology, since the latest is quite useless, I assume you mean the discrete topology, which then passes to the product when T is finite. 2) I never said the $g_\alpha$ were 1-1, in general, they are not. 3) I actually answered that in the second paragraph.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, John! My point is that if $g_{\alpha}$ is not $1-1$, G is not $1-1$ as well (for example, if $G(x) = (0,1,0,0,1,....)$, nothing can prevent an existence of $y\neq x$ such that $G(y)= (0,1,0,0,1,...)$). I also want to clarify one thing which confused me: the last paragraph disproves what we need to show, but the second to last paragraph stated that $G$ 0s homeomorphism only if $A$ is finite??

Comment: oh, yes it can, $\{g_\alpha\}$ contains in particular the functions $\delta_x$ which are 1 at $x$ and zero everywhere else, i.e. the indicator or characteristic function of the set $\{x\}$ and so $G$ is 1-1 :)

Comment: thanks for your example. But isn't $\delta_{x}$ not continuous at $x$ then?

Comment: Any function from A is continuous because A has the discrete topology

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23059/discussion-between-user177196-and-john-c).

Comment: Can't, I'm on my cellphone and it won't login

Comment: I'm so dumb:( But does your last paragraph only apply for the infinite $T$? Or it applies in general, because then it contradicts to the conclusion of your 2nd-to-last paragraph?

Comment: In general $\{0,1\}^T$ will have to have more elements than A

Comment: so we shouldn't conclude that "we may have that G is a homeomorphism only if A is finite"? Great argument for the cardinality required to be a bijection though. Many thanks!!

Comment: Well, at that point in the proof, that's the conclusion I could draw, the last paragraph then removes all doubts that remained for the finite case (and this way we didn't need to make any comparisons between infinite cardinals)

Comment: Well, at that point in the proof, that's the conclusion I could draw, the last paragraph then removes all doubts that remained for the finite case (and this way we didn't need to make any comparisons between infinite cardinals)